# IE7 + Prototype - Adding SELECT method followed by Element.addMethods() = no SELECT method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I'm new to this site so I apologize if this question's formatting looks like garbage.

In IE7, when I add a `SELECT` method with Prototype's `Element.addMethods` and then call Element.addMethods again, the method I added is gone.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Element.addMethods(
  'SELECT', 
  {
    getSelected : function(elem){
      elem = $(elem);
      if(!elem.multiple){
        return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex] ? $(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex]) : null;
      }
      return $A(elem.options).findAll(function(option){return option.selected;}).map(Element.extend);
    }
  } 
);
Element.addMethods();
function displayResult(elem){
  var selected = $(elem).getSelected();
  if(Object.isArray(selected)){
    var ret = '';
    selected.each(function(optionElem){
        ret += (ret ? ', ' : '') + option.innerHTML;
    })
    alert('['+ret+']');
  }
  else {
    alert(selected.innerHTML);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
</select>
</form>
<input type='button' value='Display' onclick='displayResult("mySelect")'>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize that in this example the call to Element.addMethods() is superfluous but it's coming from a library I don't have access to update. I do, however, have control over how the `SELECT` method is added just not where in the execution of code that it happens.

Any thoughts on how to prevent this from removing the tag-specific method, other using a decent browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.addMethods` apparently is not supposed to be called without arguments, see the [Element.addMethods documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/). Prototype itself seems to use it internally to initially add the Prototype extensions, but calling it again seems to restore a fresh prototype in IE and thus deletes all your own extensions.

I see two possible workarounds:

1. If you have access to the `Element.addMethods();` line, either remove it or replace it with

   ```
   Element.addMethods({});
   ```
2. Patch `Element.addMethods` in your code to prevent the empty call, e.g. by inserting the following redefinition before or after your `getSelected` definition (but before the `Element.addMethods();`) line:

   ```
   Element.addMethods = Element.addMethods.wrap(function(callOriginal) {
     if (arguments.length == 1) {
       callOriginal.call(Element, {});
     } else {
       var args = $A(arguments);
       args.shift();
       callOriginal.apply(Element, args);
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Excellent answer. Not sure why an empty call didn't work but, hey, whatever. I used the patch and it worked! Thanks.